# Negative Combination

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

If given $0<r<n$, then $C_r^n=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$. But what if $r<0$ since $r!$ will fail?

Comment: If $r < 0$, then $\binom{n}{r}$ is defined to be $0$.  Also, the definition $\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n - r)!}$ applies when $r \geq 0$.   We also define $\binom{n}{r} = 0$ when $r > n$.

Answer (score 1):

If $r<0$, then the combinatorial interpretation of $C^n_r$ as the number of ways to choose $r$ items from a set of $n$ objects fails, so you must specify what you mean by this expression. Normally, we define it to be $0$. Think of this as meaning that the Pascal triangle outside the normal range consists of only entries, or to represent the fact that there's no way to choose "$-1$ elements" from any set, or just as a convention to make it convenient to allow us to write
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_k \binom{n}{k}x^k$$
and have $k$ run through all integers with no problem---this is a very useful (convenient) property when working with generating functions, for instance.

Comment: I see. So if $n<0$, then will $C_r^n$ also 0?

Comment: @RANGGAJAYACIPTAWAN Nope, because we define it in a way such that the binomial theorem (the equation in my answer above) still works for arbitrary $n$. In this case we have a series expansion and the coefficients are nonzero. We define $$C^n_r=\binom nr = \frac{n(n-1)\dotsm(n-r+1)}{r(r-1)\dotsm1}$$ and use this to evaluate the generalised binomial coefficients. In other words, we no longer rely on the combinatorial interpretation. See here for more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Answer (score 1):

For integral (even complex) $n$ and integral $r$ the following definition holds:

\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{r}=
\begin{cases}
\frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-r+1)}{r!}=\frac{n^{\underline{r}}}{r!}&\quad r\geq 0\\
0&\quad r<0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

See for instance formula (5.1) in chapter *Binomial Coefficients* of *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*
by D.E. Knuth, R.L. Graham and O. Patashnik.